# How I can create multiple option in select in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I can do as individual selection for select list but can't create multiple options.

What is the reason of this & how can I do it?

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "core/spine.php",
    data: [...]
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {

    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(data.response, function(key, value) {
    $('#orderMultipleList')
    .append($("<option></option>")
    .attr("value",value)
            .text(value));
    });
```

HTML:

```
<select name="orderMultipleList[]" class="form-control"
multiple required></select>
```

JSON data response:

```
{"response":["2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018"]}
```

Result:

None.

with work code:

```
<select name="orderMultipleList" class="form-control"
required></select>
```

with doesnt work code:

```
<select name="orderMultipleList[]" class="form-control"
multiple required></select>
```

---

***EDIT: Some friends don't understand. This code don't work with more than one choice. If I only make single choices, code is working but does not work when more than one selective. This has nothing to do with PHP***

Comment: What does this give you?  `console.log($("#orderMultipleList").length)` - it will be zero because your selector `$(selector)` is looking for `<select id="orderMultipleList"` but your select doesn't have an `id=`

Comment: Are you asking how to add options from jQuery, or how to allow your <select> to have multiple values?

Comment: @freedomn-m I added `ID` in my essays but the result is the same. - Console: `0`

Comment: What is the purpose of `.attr("value",value)`?

Comment: @guest271314 Value of option

Comment: Are there elements having duplicate `id`s in the HTML `document`? Can you create a stacksnippet to demonstrate the issue? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It was a leading question... if your selector can't find your element, then the code following the selector will have nothing to operate on.  You need your selector (inside the `$()` part) to actually find DOM node.  Can you provide your actual html?  Maybe an *example* data set?  Ideally in a snippet in the question.  Have a read of [mcve].   Otherwise we can't really help you as we can easily use the code you've provided to show you a working example - but if it doesn't work for you then there's something else that's the issue, not the code you've provided here.

Comment: What is the value of `data`?

Comment: @guest271314 `$("#id").length === 0` would suggest not... but worth checking

Comment: @RobinZigmond `$.ajax({ url: RootMyAddress + "/core/spine.php", success: function (data) { ... }); `

Comment: @freedomn-m `data` could also not be valid `JSON`, or already a plain JavaScript object. An mcve should provide more detail.

Comment: Are you running your jquery inside `$(document).ready(function() { `?  (or `$(function() { ...` - could be your script is running before the html element exists.  Run that console log after the page has loaded to see if it finds it.

Comment: @Deneme2 What does `console.log(typeof data)` print before  `JSON.parse()` call?

Comment: @Deneme2 that's no use, how can I guess what your PHP script returns? Please create a MCVE as the others have said.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I updated my question

Comment: @Deneme2 _"JSON data response:"_ Is `data` a `JSON` string or JavaScript plain object? Have you read and tried the code at this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715919/how-i-can-create-multiple-option-in-select-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment96217938_54715919? `success: function (data) {console.log(typeof data, (data) instanceof Object)}` What is printed to `console`?

Comment: Looks like the service is returning a plain string and then OP is using `JSON.parse(data)` - rather than returning a plain string and letting jquery parse it into an object.

Comment: RE: Your edit.  That's why we need an [mcve] - to show what the actual problem is.  The code as provided will not generate options, so that explains "can't create options" part of the question - regardless of a single or multiple.   Can you provide some code that *does work* and then some code that *does not work* and then we can help you with your specific problem instead of guessing at the multitude of *other* errors in your code.

Comment: @guest271314 Console: `14 object`

Comment: @Deneme2 Not certain how the fist result, `14` is possible. `JSON.parse()` is not necessary if `data` is already a plain JavaScript object.

Comment: @freedomn-m I added in my question.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, I checked my PHP file and no error.

Comment: @Deneme2 _"If I only make single choices, code is working but does not work when more than one selective."_ is not immediately clear. You can demonstrate the actual client-side code completely at either https://jsfiddle or https://plnkr.co. Without using an external service you can include the full HTML and JavaScript code at the question. There is no HTML element having an `id` set to `"orderMultipleList"` at the current question. If the requirement is to append an `<option>` to each element having `name` set to `"orderMultipleList"` or `"orderMultipleList[]"` modify selector string.

Comment: @Deneme2 Even after changing the selector string passed to `jQuery()` it is not clear if you are trying to append multiple `<option>` elements to each `<select>` where the code within `.each()` would need to be adjusted to reference the correct index, or a single `<option>` to each `<select>` element. What is the expected resulting HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an id to this, as I did

```
<select name="orderMultipleList[]"  id = "orderMultipleList" class="form-control"
multiple required></select>
```

Because

```
$('#orderMultipleList')
```

needs the id, not the name

Comment: I added ID in my essays but the result is the same.

Comment: There may be errors in you 'core/spine.php' file, check it